# Rails Check Number of Child Models

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Let's say I have a `Campaign` model that `has_many :questions`.

I want to get all campaigns that have more than 3 questions. So I'd like to do something like this: `Campaign.where("questions.length > 3")`

Is there a way to do that query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a more ActiveRecord looking query to find **campaigns that have more than 3 questions**, you might try this

```
Campaign.joins(:questions).group('campaigns.id').having('count(campaign_id) > 3')
```

Answer (score 1):

The query will be:

```
Campaign.where("id IN (SELECT compaign_id 
                       FROM questions 
                       GROUP BY compaign_id
                       HAVING COUNT(*) > 3")
```

Comment: Do you know if this query is more efficient than Miles's answer?

Comment: This is interesting, my query is more efficient because `HAVING` filters the result first, it reduces the sequence scan of `Compaign`, comparing to `JOIN` first then filtering. We can use `rails db` then run the command `explain your_query` to compare. Btw, you can run the queries in `rails console` to check the running time.

Comment: Awesome stuff! Appreciate the help!